# Is there any API that returns information about "all games"?

Tags: game-design, javascript

I'm building a project about games and I need to make a "portfolio" of games.

Something like a catalog of Netflix, but about games, and I need some basic information about the game, like **Publisher**, **Genre**, **Developer**, **Release Date** and some more information.

Someone know a free API that returns the date that I need? I tried Steam API, but doesn't work for me.

**Obs:** Returns a JSON.

Comment: Are you trying to build your own API that will return some data that you manually enter, or are you asking for some service that I could find "E.T., Atari, 1982" on?

Comment: I'm trying to build the frontend. The backend is the API that I'm looking for. 

For you comment: No, I'm no trying to build my own API, yes, I'm asking for some service that I could find "E.T., Atari, 1982" and some information about this game, like Developer, Publisher, Release Date and others.

Comment: Note that GameDev.StackExchange is a site for getting help with making new games & game mods. What you're looking for here is a source of information *about* games that *have already been made*, which is a different specialty than making new games themselves. You might not find the answers you're looking for on this particular site. I recommend researching websites that publish lists of entries on games like MetaCritic, or combining results from multiple more [specialized](http://tovgdb.smallcity.ca/) [databases](https://queerlyrepresent.me/database/spreadsheet).

Comment: I'm afraid questions asking for the existence of some service or functionality are basically list-of questions, and thus considered too broad here.

Comment: You might want to consider creating a scraper for wikipedia....

Comment: Also check where other game DB sites get this info from.